# Name change on ticket

Tags: air-travel, tickets

I booked an airline ticket with my family (1 Female & 3 Male). But my program was postponed with some reason. I want on my ticket my parents visit, my father & 3 my brother. Can you replace the ticket of my to my parents? Or can I visit later on this ticket?

Comment: Which airline did you buy the ticket from?

Comment: Without full details of the ticket, this is unanswerable.

Answer (score 2):

Almost no airlines allow name changes on tickets. The ticket must be cancelled and re-purchased (perhaps with refund of taxes). There are a couple of exceptions for low cost carriers that allow a name change for a fee. If you name the airline, we can point to the specific terms and conditions.

As Zach mentions, some tickets are changeable (date and destination, but often not name) for a fee. Typically a ticket must be repriced if it is changed before departure, and there will also be a change fee. After departure, the ticket may often be changed just for the change fee but will be priced using the historical price of the ticket on the purchase date.

For full details, it will be necessary to know exact fare details, airline and dates in order to locate the fare rules if you don't already have them.